# How is it computationally possible to calculate ANOVA of microarrays with interactions of 4000 genes and 7 times

Tags: anova, microarray, time-complexity

M. Kerr and G. Churchill [use ANOVA to separate changes in gene expressions from effects due to the used arrays or dye](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC55356/) using the interaction terms time*gene

As they are dealing with yeast which has about 4000 genes and they use 7 Arrays monitoring, they should amount to about 20000-30000 interaction terms in their model.

I tried an anova using `aov(expression ~ gene*time)` in R to reproduce their results using [the same dataset](http://cmgm.stanford.edu/pbrown/sporulation/additional/spospread.txt) as was used in the paper.

However that modelling step takes exponential time due to the gene-time interactions and I'm unable to model more than about 200 genes.

My Question therefore: Am I doing it wrong (quite likely so) so how is ANOVA performed to a obtain estimates gene*time-specific behaviour while avoiding exponential complexity?